# Is metallic hydrogen an example of exciton?

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, semiconductor-physics, hydrogen, jupiter

I know that in [exciton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exciton) an electron is excited and goes from valence band to conducting band leaving an electron hole which is positively charged, soon Jupiter came into my mind and then this question. Also what is the different between plasma and exciton?

Answer (score 0):

An exciton is a quasi-particle describing the excited electronic state od insulators or semiconductors.

Metallic Hydrogen, at temperatures and pressures it is a stable phase, is a conductor in its ground state.